# Defense Grid: more towers or upgrades?

Tags: defense-grid-awakening

In Defense Grid: The Awakening, is it more cost-efficient to build more towers or upgrade existing ones?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I asked devs the same question and turned out there is no difference from both cost and damage points of views (except for temporals and commander towers). I upgrade towers that are located in most valuable places (i.e. where aliens pass several times) where space is limited.

Quote from a dev:

> The choice is actually entirely up to
>   you.
>
> level 1 gun tower - cost 100
>
> level 2 gun tower - cost 200 (total
>   paid = 300)
>
> level 3 gun tower - cost 400 (total
>   paid = 700)
>
> The damage a level 2 gun tower does is
>   exactly 3 times as much as a level 1
>   gun tower.  The damage a level 3 gun
>   tower is exactly 7 times as much as a
>   level 1 gun tower.
>
> Essentially, a single level 3 gun
>   tower is equal to seven level 1 gun
>   towers.  They do the same total damage
>   and the total cost of each are also
>   the same.
>
> If you're building a maze, the seven
>   towers is probably the better choice. 
>   If you're limited on space, or you
>   have a kill zone setup with a temporal
>   tower, then perhaps the full upgraded
>   gun tower is the better choice.
>
> It really depends on your playstyle
>   and the choices you make for any given
>   map.
>
> By the way, the above example is true
>   for all towers.  (Except the Temporal
>   and Command tower, they're special.)

Comment: usually, when you have enough space, and technically it doesn't matter, mutiple towers give the advantage over a single tower, as they're faster to place and can spread out the damage over multiple targets.

Comment: Upgrades give increased range, don't they?

Answer (score 2):

I found that upgrading always works better for me than to place a lot of towers
Check out what each upgrade does, it shows how much the damage, rate of fire, and range would be increased when you upgrade; I think it becomes clear when you compare damage vs cost.

A level 3 (red) gun tower for example, is way more powerful than a lot level one (green) ones.

[Here](http://defensegrid.hiddenpath.com/node/311)'s an interesting article on that tower, and some design decisions.

There are challenges where you can only build level 1 towers, play that and experience first hand how the gameplay changes.

Comment: I tend to think that red gun towers are too powerful, many times you can pass the level by spamming them, without caring about other kinds of turrets.

Comment: @Gnoupi: you sure there aren't any bullet resistant types in the game? I only have the demo so far (so i can't check) but that seems reasonable. Plus, the other towers do have their niches.

Comment: @RCIX - there are, and you are more effective with correct turrets. But there are several levels in which you can just spam them and win (with some losses, though).

Comment: @Gnoupi: Considering it is not too hard to beat the game with no losses whatsoever, I don't think that's a very good strategy.

Answer (score -2):

Although I have not myself played Defense Grid, in every other tower defense game I've played it is much more cost effective to upgrade existing ones.

Comment: Well there is a trade off.  Usually for the first several rounds you build towers incessantly.  Then, you start upgrading.  In my experience two towers of level n are usually better than one tower of level n+1 and only mildly more expensive.  This is especially true of towers that target one creep at a time.

Comment: Depends on how the towers upgrade in the game.  For instance, in Sanctum it's more cost-effective to build more towers than to upgrade existing ones.